# How do I explicitly find the norm of $I = \text{Card}(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]/I)?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Say we have number field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$, where $d$ is either $1$ or $2$ mod $4$, so ring of integers is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$. Suppose we have an ideal of ring of integers $I$. Now, $I$ can be written as$$\mathbb{Z}(a + b\sqrt{-d}) + \mathbb{Z}(e + f\sqrt{-d}),$$where the two basis elements are clearly $\mathbb{Z}$-linearly independent. Given $a$, $b$, $e$, $d$, $f$, how do I explicitly find the norm of $I$, defined to be $$\text{Card}(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]/I)?$$

Comment: Closely related questions have come up here before. Maybe you'll find something helpful at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398159/how-to-calculate-the-norm-of-an-ideal or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366363/norm-of-ideals-in-quadratic-number-fields or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294102/how-do-i-compute-the-norm-of-a-non-principal-ideal-of-the-ring-of-integers-of-a

Comment: Given two generators $I=(a+b\sqrt{-d},c+e\sqrt{-d})$, you only have to compute the quotient $\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+d,a+bX,c+eX)$, which is not that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own method is just to thrash about unsystematically, as suggested by @MooS. But here’s a presystematic approach that might work. Let $J_1$ be the ideal generated by your first quantity $z_1=a+b\sqrt{-d}$ (not merely the integer multiples of $z_1$), and $J_2$ be the ideal generated by $z_2=e+f\sqrt{-d}$. You know the norms of the $J_i$: $J_1$ has norm $a^2+db^2$ and $J_2$ has norm $e^2+df^2$. If you know the decompositions of the rational primes that divide the norms, then you should be able to find the prime decomposition of $J_1$ and $J_2$, and so of $J_1+J_2$. That will tell you the norm.